# "The active result contains no fields" using PDO with MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am in the process of converting some old PHP pages to use PDO.

Below are two simplified queries (not my actual queries) to aid understanding of the problem I'm having...

```
SELECT afield INTO #temptable FROM atable WHERE anotherfield = 'somevalue';

SELECT afield,anotherfield,onemorefield FROM atable 
WHERE afield NOT IN (SELECT * FROM #temptable);
```

The above query throws the error described in the title (more completely it throws "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.'")

If I alter the query like this...

```
with (SELECT afield INTO #temptable FROM atable 
WHERE anotherfield = 'somevalue') AS temptable;

SELECT afield,anotherfield,onemorefield FROM atable 
where afield NOT IN (SELECT * FROM temptable);
```

This seems to get around the error, but this version of the query is horribly horribly inefficient because it appears to run the temptable query for every single field comparison in the other query.

Is there a way to make the first form (which creates a temporary table once) work with PDO?

It worked fine on the old page which used mssql.

**EDIT:** I know I can probably do this in a 'messy' way by creating a real table,  run it in php,  then run the second query (in a separate php call) , then run a third query to drop the first table.   But I'd rather not have to resort to that! :)

Comment: Note that SQL keywords like `SELECT, WHERE, FROM ...` should be uppercased. This will improve readability. You should start with this first

Comment: Do you actually separating the queries by a semicolon `;` ?

Comment: Tried that.  Made no difference.

Comment: I have no SQL Server and can't test it. It can be a problem with the underlying sqlclient C library

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you are using a stored procedure then use

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

The problem is that the stored procedure returns a result containing the number of rows affected as the first result.

[Microsoft Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx)

Comment: I wish I had found this before trying my query so many different ways.
Thank you!

Comment: DB::select('SET NOCOUNT ON ; EXEC stored_procedure ')

Comment: In my case, I was not using stored procedure and it worked too.

Answer (score 17):

The PDO engine sees this query as returning two result sets (the older mssql engine probably just ignored all but the last query in an overall query string). I have managed to make it work by skipping over the first result set (the temporary table) using the following command

```
$statement->nextRowset();
```

And then using `$statement->fetch();` as normal

Answer (score 11):

If you are using a `StoredProcedure` and doing something as:

```
DB::select("EXEC [storedprocedure] $param1,$param2;");
```

As per above, the `PDO` expects the `DB::select` statement to return some data. But as your `StoredProcedure` does not return any data, you can change **`DB::select` TO `DB::update`** as belows:

```
DB::update("EXEC [storedprocedure] $param1,$param2;");
```

After this the error should no longer appear.

Comment: My SP was selecting something only on error.  By selecting something on success as well, I was able to get this working.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue and the above answers helped, but the answers here assume things:

1. You have access to modfy the sproc with `SET NOCOUNT ON` and you
   want to do this
2. You're sure you need to move to the next rowset
   `$statement->nextRowset();`

In my case I am using a generic method to pull back data from multiple sprocs where I may or may not have this issue and needed to check before incrementing the rowset.

I used the following:

```
while($stmt->columnCount() === 0 && $stmt->nextRowset()) {
    // Advance rowset until we get to a rowset with data
}

if($stmt->columnCount() > 0) {
    // We found something with data, do stuff.
    // Code here
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone else running into a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Laravel5 in this version you should execute

```
DB::select('SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC stored_procedure'. $param1.','...$paramN);
```

It worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I am using laravel5 and this is how I fixed the issue;

```
DB::select("SET ANSI_NULLS ON; SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;EXEC [storedprocedure] $param1,$param2;");
```

Comment: Thanks Kamaro. I am on Laravel5 as well and this helped. I ran `DB::select('SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC stored_procedure');` and it worked perfectly.