# The active result for the query contains no fields

Tags: php, database, fetch, sqlsrv

I am getting the following error: `The active result for the query contains no fields`

Below is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbconnect_three.php';
include 'dbconnect.php';
include 'dbconnect_two.php';

$uname      = $_SESSION['user'];
$email      = $_SESSION['email'];
$message_id = $_POST['mess_id'];
$maxseq     = $_POST['maxseq'];
$otheruser  = $_POST['otheruser'];

//The part below is the one that does the query to retrieve the messages from the database

$sql_message_retriver         = "SELECT message FROM inbox WHERE message_id='$message_id' ";
$sql_message_retriever_result = sqlsrv_query($conn_three, $sql_message_retriever);


while ($sql_message_result_display = SQLSRV_FETCH_ARRAY($sql_message_retriever_result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $message_string = $sql_message_result_display['message'];
    echo "<right>$message_string</right>";
}

$seen   = 2;
$maxseq = $maxseq + 1;

echo "<form action=// method=post>";
echo "Messageinput type=text name=update>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=message_id value=$message_id>"; // gotta fix this part
echo "<input type=hidden name=maxseq value=$maxseq>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=otheruser value=$otheruser>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=otheremail value=$otheremail>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=keyes value=$keyes>";
echo "<input type=submit name=submit value=Reply>";
echo "</form>";

print_r(sqlsrv_errors());

?>
```

The exact error I get:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => IMSSP
        [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
        [1] => -28
        [code] => -28
        [2] => The active result for the query contains no fields.
        [message] => The active result for the query contains no fields.
    )
)
```

Here is one suggestion i found to solve the problem from other forums: use the `sqlsrv_next_result`. I used it and it says ODBC function sequence error(something like that).

Here is something else to note, when i change my sql statement to say like this:

```
$sql_id_two="SELECT message 
             FROM   inbox 
             WHERE  message_id = '$message_id' 
                    AND to_email = '$email' 
                     OR from_email = '$email'";
```

It actually works and displays the message. It's weird.

Can anyone explain this error message?

Comment: Ewwww... unsanitized get variable in database query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out whats wrong,  i made a spelling error with my sql statement. so i inserted the wrong spelling for resource 2 for the sqlsrv_query. how can i be soooo stupid.

Comment: Don't worry; it happens to the best and Microsoft isn't known for precisely helpful error messages.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, [using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735898/the-active-result-contains-no-fields-using-pdo-with-ms-sql), i had to call [nextRowset()](https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) because i was trying to read columns from the result of an `insert` before the `select`.

The SQLSRV [equivalent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-next-result.php) is:

```
mixed sqlsrv_next_result ( resource $stmt )
```