# "The active result for the query contains no fields" using MSSQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Although this question has already been answered multiple times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735898/the-active-result-contains-no-fields-using-pdo-with-ms-sql), [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/507), and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fd6015cd-d42f-470d-b8c7-ae9e6786f59c/stored-procedure-returns-empty-result-set?forum=sqldriverforphp), none of these solutions could solve the issue for me.

I am trying to use PHP to fetch data from an MSSQL database. Although any query that I attempt to perform yields the same error message:

> The active result for the query contains no fields.

Below is the code that I use to execute the query.

```
<?
    include 'private.php'; // contains the servername, database, userID and password

    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$userID, "PWD"=>$password);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";

        $query = 'USE data; SELECT * FROM Users;';

        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query );

        if(sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt))
        {
            echo 'success';
        }

        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt);
        if ($row === false)
        {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }

        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            echo $row['Name'].", ".$row['Value']."<br />";
        }

        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
    }   
    else {
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
```

Surprisingly, executing the same query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio works without any errors and executing queries that do not return information work fine aswell.

Note that I have already tried using `SET NOCOUNT ON;`, which is recommended in some answers regarding the same topic.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: how did you solved this problem??