# Converting mssql to sqlsrv in php. Stored procedure no returning correct result when successful

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv, php-mssql

I am upgrading from php 5.5.30 to php 7.2.7.  So I have switch code from mssql to sqlsrv.  I have php that runs a stored procedure with input parameters that prints the result and then returns a 1 or 0 depending on if it is successful or not, and the transNum.  It returns 0 correctly, but when it is successful, it prints the result, but returns nothing.

**OLD Code PHP:**

```
$transNum = 12;
$dept = "fgr";
$reprint = 1;
$query = mssql_init('STR_PrintBarcodeLabel', $conn);
mssql_bind($query, '@transNum', $transNum, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 11);
mssql_bind($query, '@dept', $dept, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 15);
mssql_bind($query, '@reprint', $reprint, SQLBIT, false, false, 1);
$result = mssql_execute($query);
$row = mssql_fetch_row($result);
mssql_free_statement($query);
echo $row[0];
```

This would print to the file then return a 1 if sucessful.

**PHP:**

```
$transNum = 12
$dept = "fgr";
$reprint = 1;

$query = "{call STR_PrintBarcodeLabel( ?, ?, ?)}";
$params = array( array($transNum, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN), 
                 array($dept, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN), 
                 array($reprint, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN));
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0] . "<br />" . $dept . "<br />" . $transNum . "<br />";
```

When an inncorrect transNum is entered, it outputs:

```
0
fgr
12
```

When a correct transNum is entered, it outputs:

```
<blank line>
fgr
1234567
```

The blank line should be a 1.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
                 update STR_ItemBarcodePrint

                 set printed = 'true'

                 where trans_num = @transNum



                 select 1, @transNum

          end

          else

          begin

                 select 0, @transNum

          end

END
```

So the stored procedure is being called and does its job except it doesn't return 1 anymore when its successful.  It does return the proper result of 0 if the transNum is invalid or its not a reprint.  Is there a reason the successful completion of the store procedure doesn't return a 1 using sqlsrv when it does using mssql?

**Update: Solved**
The solution was to add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the stored procedure.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: I suppose `var_dump` it? Is it an empty string? A null? A Boolean? See the bit on *Return Values* [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php).

Comment: So I did var_dump with a valid transNum and got : `test1.php:37:boolean false` and then on an invalid transNum and got `test1.php:37: array (size=3)  0=>int 0  ' '=> string '4606773' (length =7)    1 => string '4606773' (length=7)`

Comment: I think this might be your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466503/calling-stored-procedure-from-php-using-pdo-to-mssql-server-using-input-paramter Specifically the parenthesis? Also, your code has an unclosed `{` bracket. This is also a [good resource](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/03/10/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-whats-the-difference-part-2/).

Comment: Thanks.  I have been using that resource to make the switch from mssql to sqlsrv.  I also used this code `$query = "EXEC STR_PrintBarcodeLabel @transNum=?, @dept=?, @reprint=?";` and got the same results.  The missing } was a typo when I was writing the inital post.  I guess it looks like there is an error with the sqlsrv_fetch_array if it is returning a false boolean.

Comment: Agreed. Strange thought that it "works" with an invalid transNum. Pretty sure it would expect `"exec STR_PrintBarcodeLabel ?, ?, ?";` Can you share the procedures SQL?

Comment: I added the stored procedure.  The `exec` command doesn't change results regardless of whether it has just `?` or `@varname=?`.  The print file is created with the correct info when the store procedure has a valid transNum.

Comment: Lot going on there. I'm focused on the IF EXISTS main conditional block. You've double checked things are kosher? Removed PHP from the mix? Not a case of something else having changed?

Comment: Everything up to the `EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell  @cmd, no_output` works because the print file is created and it has the correct info in it.  The server is being run on wamp which I upgraded from 2.5 to 3.0.6.  Then I switched it to PHP 7.2.7 and added the microsoft sql server 5.2 driver.  If there was something wrong in the first part of the stored procedure then it shouldn't create the printfile.

Comment: I added `print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));` and got `Array([0]=>IMSSP[SQLSTATE]=>IMSSP[1]=> -28[code]=> -28[2]=> The active result for the query contains no fields. [message]=>The active result for the query contains no fields.))`

Comment: Bingo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735898/the-active-result-contains-no-fields-using-pdo-with-ms-sql Had nagging deje vu.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I found a similar post that also suggesting using `SET NOCOUNT ON;`.  I will test it out and update the main post if it works.